# Different response entity body based on accept header with Spring WebMVC REST controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, xml-serialization

I have a controller with a method signature like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{project:[A-Z0-9_+\\.\\(\\)=\\-]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> lookupProject(@PathVariable String project,
        @RequestParam(value = "fields", required = false) String fields,
        @RequestParam(value = "asList", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean asList);
```

I am returning for JSON a `Collection<Object>` or `Map<String, Object>`. This isn't suitable for XML. I'd rather return a `Project` object.

Is there a clean way to determine which content type will be produced? The work-around would be another method which produces XML only and returns the `Project` object. I'd rather like to avoid duplicate code.

I am on Spring 3.1.3-RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring documentation, your produces param will return content based on the Accept, i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someUrl/", produces="application/*")
public Project someControllerMethod(...)
```

If the method takes in application/xml, the method will produce XML, if application/json, it will produce json, etc.

You just need marshallers set up for the appropriate object types.

Documentation here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces()

Comment: Jackon is already registered by default. JSON works flawlessly. I do not intend to modify the Jackson Converter for my custom object.

Comment: The reason I brought up Jackson initially is due to the fact you don't mention it once in your question. If I understand right, you're trying to create a generic method that accepts all requests then binds to a specific model?  Is there a reason why you're not splitting these into separate methods?

Comment: Yes, there is one. I do want to repeat code. Simply based on the negotiated content type, I'd like to return the appropriate object.

Comment: Take in the HttpServletRequest object, check the content type and marshal appropriately.  I wouldn't recommend this, though, makes testing more of a headache and leads to code obfuscation.

Comment: This is exactly what I do **not** want to do. If I do so, I don't need the Spring Framework. I guess there is no builtin solution. I will maybe raise a ticket.

Comment: Well what you're doing isn't normal, Spring champions testable design, and testable design would suggest you break the method up into multiple methods, each with their own @RequestMapping(... consumes="contentType"), where consumes is something like consumes="application/json".

Comment: Updated post, think this might answer the question after rereading again.

Comment: Well, up until there does not seem to be a clean way to handle this in a single method. I will need to do what I have presumed: two methods w/ appropriate `consumes`. This is what I meant by workaround in my question.

Comment: No this will handle both, due to the application/*, just have to make sure your request encoding is either application/json or application/xml (you can enter a comma separated list as well rather than *, so if you wanted text/xml instead, for example)  The requested encoding type is the resulting response type.

Comment: This still does not solve my problem. I do not know which content type will be served by the framework unless I inspect the Accept header.

Comment: Read the documentation: "The format is a sequence of media types ("text/plain", "application/*), with a request only mapped if the Accept matches one of these media types." So send either media type to this controller method, it will be mapped auto-magically and you can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Content type to be produced will depend on type acceptable by the client.One solution for this is already mentioned, using produces attribute.Another solution is using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, which can resolve views based on accept header or other mechanism.

Refer the documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html

Example:http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Comment: I guess, my question was misunderstood. I want to know which of these will be picked up actually.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit, I think Dardo's solution is best, you could inspect the object type with your XMLHttpMessageConverter, and cast differently if it's a Project object.

Comment: Well, I do not intend to modify the builtin XML message converter, it works very well the way it is. The check needs to happen in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Framework 4.1 you can use a ResponseBodyAdvice to modify the value returned from an @ResponseBody or ResponseEntity method just before it is written out.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html.

Answer (score -3):

I ended up in splitting in two methods.

Public methods have been renamed to `lookupAsType`. Both delegate/return

```
String[] fieldsArray = StringUtils.split(fields, ',');
return lookup(project, fieldsArray, asList, mediaType);
```

The new method `lookup` has the same code s before but contains not an if clause for the media types.

```
if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
    body = projectValues;
} else if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)) {
    body = new Project(projectValues);
} else {
    throw new NotImplementedException("Project lookup is not implemented for media type '" + mediaType + "'");
}
```

The bad thing is that MediaType is not a enum but an ugly class.

Comment: Have you even tried my answer?  You're misusing constructs of the framework.

Comment: I had `produces = {app/json, app/xml}` already before but with that I do gain nothing because I still do not know which media type will be written.

Comment: The media type written will match what is taken in, as long as you have marshallers set up for both JSON and XML for your Project object, if you take in application/xml or application/json xml or json will be produced, you don't have to check it in your method.

Comment: Well, the  point is that I do not want `Project` being serialized when JSON is requested but only the `projectValues`.

Comment: I see, I think I finally understand, will let you know if I stumble on a different way of implementing that, but since you're returning two different types of objects, not sure it will be possible.

Comment: OK, probably I have not made my position clear enough. I searialize a different object according the requested media type. With the wrapping methods it works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, that way should work fine, not exactly elegant, but will get the job done.

Comment: I might raise an issue for that in spring. I guess I am not the only one who would like to have such a feature.